# How to make TextBox's text editable after dynamically creating the TextBox control?

Tags: wpf, textbox, readonly

I've created a control array of textboxes and they are in a grid but I can't access the box to change text. So far I tried to solve it with:

```
                fields[row, col].IsEnabled = true;
                fields[row, col].IsReadOnly = false;
```

but it didn't worked.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int wdth = 40;
    int hght = 32;
    for (int row = 0; row <= 8; row++)
    {
        ColumnDefinition colDef = new ColumnDefinition();
        RowDefinition rowDef = new RowDefinition();
        colDef.MinWidth = wdth;
        colDef.MaxWidth = wdth;
        rowDef.MinHeight = hght;
        rowDef.MaxHeight = hght;
        grdAdtn.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef);
        grdAdtn.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef); 
    };
    TextBox[,] fields = new TextBox[9, 9];
    FontFamily font = new FontFamily("Courier New");
    for(int row=0; row <= 8; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col <= 8; col++){
            fields[row,col]=new TextBox();
            fields[row, col].Name = "txt" + row.ToString() + "i"+col.ToString();
            if ((row==0)&&(col==0))
            {
                fields[row, col].Text = "+";
            }
            else if (row == 0)
            {
                fields[row, col].Text = (col+1).ToString();
            }
            else if (col == 0)
           {
               fields[row, col].Text = (row+1).ToString();
           }
           else
           {
               fields[row, col].Text = "??";
           }
            fields[row, col].FontSize = 22;
            fields[row, col].FontFamily = font;
            fields[row, col].MaxLength = 2;
            grdAdtn.Children.Add((fields[row, col]));
            Grid.SetColumn(fields[row,col], col);
            Grid.SetRow(fields[row,col], row);
            fields[row, col].Width = wdth-2;
            fields[row, col].Height = hght-2;
            fields[row, col].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            fields[row, col].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            fields[row, col].HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            fields[row, col].VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            fields[row, col].IsEnabled = true;
            fields[row, col].IsReadOnly = false;
           }
    }
}
```

Any clues?

Also I can focus them with `fields[row,col].Focus()` so they are apparently enabled but I can't write text and when I click with mouse on some of the TextBoxes it doesn't transfer focus on that TextBox (pressing tab works but I need more functionality). It doesn't do anything at all as far I can see.
Do I need to manually add event handlers for MouseDown/MouseUp after creating the TextBox dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your Window_Loaded into solution, built and it works just fine - I can change the text in generated textboxes just fine... what else do you have in your XAML besides

```
<Grid x:Name="grdAdtn"/>
```